# Conflict between dark mode and dialog

Tags: java, android

I have a little problem and my app. By default the dark mode (AppCompat Night) is disabled, ok. When a new version of my app is installed or installed for the first time, it shows a dialog with what's new and so on. But when this dialog appears, it appears as if dark mode was on (it appears dark), and his buttons (ok and cancel) do not work. They only work again when I click the multitasking button on my device and return to the app, is this a system bug? (Android 6.0).

Comment: by the way you describe it, it is not really related to dark mode or you just switch dark mode off after the dialog appears

Comment: I had a similar problem when using setDefaultNightMode with activities that were not inheriting from AppCompatActivity. You might need to extend it.

Comment: Well, I need the dark mode to be off before the dialog appears.

Comment: Yes, I get that. But if you're setting it to disabled on startup/application and the activity is not inheriting from AppCompatActivity you could get the problem you're describing where you have to force a configuration change in order for the nightmode to switch properly.

Comment: my activity extends AppCompatActivity yes I have following code after super oncreate 
   AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);
  

    
  init();    (Show news dialog) But the dialogue appears as if the dark mode is on!